# Enumerating combinations by product

Tags: enumeration, combinatorics

I have three lists a, b, c. Each list contains a number of integers in sorted order.

For the sake of the example let:

```
a = [2, 2, 7]
b = [4, 6, 9]
c = [3, 6, 8]
```

My goal is to enumerate all possible products of elements from the three lists in increasing order.

The minimal product is of course `a[0]*b[0]*c[0]`. In the example, the second-lowest product is `a[0]*b[1]*c[0]`. And so on.

I'm trying to find a general solution for an arbitrary number of lists. I struggle to generalize the step from having the k-th lowest product to the (k+1) lowest product.

I don't want to enumerate all possible products and then sort them, because I'm dealing with a potentially very large number of lists and may be interested only in, e.g., the top 1000 combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we want to get a time complexity of `O(N * K)` where `N` is the number of lists and `K` is the `K`-th product.
We maintain a pointer at the beginning of each list (for simplicity I call this `P[i]` - `i`'th pointer at list `i`, and `L[i]` - the `i`'th list).

Initially `P[i] = 0` for each list (because we start indexing the lists from 0)

`Step 1`: The first product is `L[0][P[1]] * L[1][P[2]] * .. L[N][P[N]]`.

`Step 2`: For the next step we are interested in minimizing the next product.
We select `j (0<=j<=N)` for which `L[j][P[j] + 1]` is minimum. We increment `P[j]` by `1` and then go at `Step 1` for computing the next product. I think it's clear that the next product should be the minimum of all possibilities.

If you want to count the number of unique products you simply maintain a counter which you will increment only if the current product is different than the previous.

You can still improve this algorithm to `O(log(N) * K)` by using a priority queue in order to get the minimum at `Step 2`.